# How to touch a file at shutdown

Tags: shutdown, systemd, services

I'm working on Ubuntu 16.04.3 and I need to create a file at the OS shutdown time.

After reading this link: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39226/how-to-run-a-script-with-systemd-right-before-shutdown

I created a file named `test.service` at `/lib/systemd/system/` and here is the content:

```
[Unit]
Description=test

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/home/test.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here is `/home/test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

touch /home/myfile
```

However, after rebooting the system, I cannot see any file named `/home/myfile`.

Comment: Did you follow all the steps including the `systemctl` ones?

Comment: @NPsoft What do you mean by steps

Comment: Just creating a service file won't be enough. You need to enable it as well using `systemctl` commands.

Comment: Also ensure that `test.sh` is executable. Run the script from the terminal to ensure that it works. I have a feeling that `touch /home/myfile` may require permissions. (Think Why?)

Comment: @NPsoft  Thanks a lot, now I do see the file has been created. However, it seems that it happens at OS-startup, instead of at OS-shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the line `RemainAfterExit=true`, so your service stops after executing `true`. Add it to the [Service] section and it should work.

Also you should rather put your unit files into `/etc/systemd/system/`.